# How can i delete old images in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I want to remove old images in my public folder when he want to change him profile photo.

ProfileController:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048'
    ]);
            
    $imageName = $request->user()->id.'-'.time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('users'), $imageName);
    $path = "users/".$imageName;
    $request->user()->image = $path;
    $request->user()->save();
}
```

i tried somethings but i cant do it.
Thanks for your replys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer user:8009914(DadoH)

He writed storage_path(/...) and it doesnt work for me but when i changed to public_path(/..) its now work for me.

```
'''
thats my code example its working:
$fileToDelete2 = public_path('/').$request->user()->image;
    
    
    
                if ($request->user()->image && file_exists($fileToDelete2))
                {
        
                    //this works
                    unlink($fileToDelete2);
    
                }'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I am allowing to upload avatar for users too, but I am not deleleting old files. But I tried to amend it just now and I found one solution working.

I was looking also at offical docs, but their solution is not working: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#deleting-files

Note: I have left few comments and unused variables in the code for better explanation, feel free to do a cleanup.

**UserController.php -> update(Request $request, User $user)**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
...
$formFields = $request->validate([
    'avatar' => 'nullable|max:1024|image',
]);

if ($request->hasFile('avatar'))
{
    //this file is impossible to delete, giving up
    $fileToDelete1 = asset($user->avatar);

    //this file can be deleted, file_exists returns true
    $fileToDelete2 = storage_path('app/public').'/'.$user->avatar;
    $fileToDelete3 = public_path('/').'/'.$user->avatar;

    if ($user->avatar && file_exists($fileToDelete2))
    {
        //not able to delete file like this
        Storage::delete($fileToDelete2);

        //this works
        unlink($fileToDelete2);

        //or this, depends where you are storing file
        //dont forget to add it to if/file_exists condition
        unlink($fileToDelete3);

    }
    $formFields['avatar'] = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'public');
}
$user->update($formFields);
```

Comment: ErrorException

unlink(/var/www/html/storage/app/public/users/1-1679384955.jpg): No such file or directory     how can i fix that?

Comment: and file_exist return false but this file directory is available. i dont know why it dont find file directory

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use the following code:

```php
    // ...
    $request->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

    // If the user has an image, delete it
    if ($request->user()->image) {
        \Storage::delete(public_path($request->user()->image));
    }

    // ...
```

---

However, uploading files directly to the public folder isn't a good practice. Most of the experienced Laravel developers prefer to create a symbolic link from the `laravelApp/public/storage` to the `laravelApp/storage/app/public` directory.

With the symbolic link, Laravel looks `laravelApp/storage/app/public/photos/user1.jpeg` path for the request made to `https://website.com/storage/photos/user1.jpeg`.

You can get more information about the symbolic link from the following links:

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk - [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230315084325/https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)
- https://dev.to/tvpeter/file-storage-and-symbolic-links-in-laravel-1m96 - [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330124342/https://dev.to/tvpeter/file-storage-and-symbolic-links-in-laravel-1m96)